# SQL Server checking for non-equivalent column/rows with grouping

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, equals, rows, equivalent

I would like to process some data in SQL SERVER, do a little QA and get the 'answer' at the same time.

The table represents a test and if the test did not give a 100% match, it was run in duplicate.

In this table the following codes are applicable and they are in ascending order of priority:
 1) -99 test was skipped
 2) 00 test was not 100% match
 3) Anything > 00 is 100% match (e.g. 01, 02, 01-01 etc)

So a couple of things I need to do.

First, for each SampleID I need to pick out where 01 > 00 > -99
Second, I need to know if any test had 100% match (e.g. #3) and the tests disagree.  An example of this is 11-0010-P1 (below) where Run2=01 and Run3=02

I kinda got the first part with the following code, but I cannot get the MAXIMUM of the ROWNUMBER() part of the query.

I am really stuck on the second part.

All help would be appreciated !

```
    DECLARE @TempTable TABLE (SampleID varchar(10), TestRun int, TestResult varchar(max))

    INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES('11-0003-P1', 1,'-99')    
    INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES('11-0004-P1', 1, '00')    
    INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES('11-0005-P1', 1, '01')
    INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES('11-0007-P1', 1,'-99')    
    INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES('11-0007-P1', 2, '00')    
    INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES('11-0007-P1', 3, '00')    
    INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES('11-0008-P1', 1,'-99')
    INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES('11-0008-P1', 2, '02')
    INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES('11-0008-P1', 3, '02')    
    INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES('11-0009-P1', 1, '00')
    INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES('11-0009-P1', 2, '07')
    INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES('11-0009-P1', 3, '07')
    INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES('11-0010-P1', 1, '00')
    INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES('11-0010-P1', 2, '01')
    INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES('11-0010-P1', 3, '02')    

    SELECT SampleID, TestRun, TestResult,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SampleID
                        ORDER BY 
                           CASE TestResult
                             WHEN '-99' THEN 1
                             WHEN  '00' THEN 2
                             ELSE 3
                             END
                        )  AS RowNumber
     FROM @TempTable
     ORDER BY SampleID, TestRun
```

The results should be like this:

```
 SampleID   TestResult
 11-0003-P1    -99
 11-0004-P1    00
 11-0005-P1    01
 11-0007-P1    00
 11-0008-P1    02
 11-0009-P1    07
 11-0010-P1    Err 01:02
```

**it would ideal to actually give the conflicting values (e.g. 01:02 for 11-0010-P1) but not totally necessary, the Err flag would be OK.

Comment: +1 . . . By the way, this is a good question.  You provide sample data and a script to test!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confused by the window functions, because you can solve this using regular `group by`:

```
select SampleId,
       (case when max(TestResult) in ('-99', '00') then max(TestResult)
             when max(TestResult) = min(case when TestResult not in ('-99', '00') then TestResult end)
             then max(TestResult)
             else 'Err '+min(case when TestResult not in ('-99', '00') then TestResult end)+':'+max(TestResult)
        end)
from TempTable
group by SampleId;
```

There are two important points here.  The first is that '-99' < '00' < xx for strings as well as numbers.  So, `max()` works to find the last test result.

The second is finding the "other" value, where there is more than one value.  For this, the query uses a conditional minimum -- that is, find the minimum value excluding '-99' and '00'.

The SQL Fiddle is [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4173b/5), which is why I change `@TempTable` to `TempTable`.

Answer (score 0):

Following query will give you maximum row number, but I dont understand the condition for 'Err' can you elaborate it?

Query:

```
select SampleID, TestResult
from (
SELECT SampleID, TestRun, TestResult,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SampleID
                        ORDER BY 
                           CASE TestResult
                             WHEN '-99' THEN 1
                             WHEN  '00' THEN 2
                             ELSE 3
                             END desc
                        )  AS RowNumber
     FROM @TempTable
  ) t
where RowNumber = 1
ORDER BY SampleID, TestRun
```

Comment: Dang it - I messed up the err (error function).  It should read 02:07 (non-equivalent rows)

Comment: No I did it correct.  If you look at 11-0010-P1 you'll notice that Run 2 does not equal Run 3.